# Как создать npm-пакет, который будет иметь возможность запускаться прямо из терминала по своему имени?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Интересует, как создаются такие npm-пакеты, которые в дальнейшем можно вызывать прямо из терминала?

Например, при установке пакета express-generator, в папку, где лежит бинарник node'а и npm'а (например `~/.local/bin/node/bin/`) добавляется ссылка на `../lib/node_modules/[package]/bin/`. То есть, поскольку путь к node'у лежит в переменной окружения `$PATH`, то и к этому пакету тоже теперь есть доступ прямо из терминала. Я могу просто написать `express` и этот файл начнет выполняться ('~/.local/bin/node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js`).

Что удивляет еще больше, так это 2 другие вещи: почему пакет называется express-generator, а запускается он командой express? И почему этот файл является обычным `.js` файлом, но запускается из терминала как ни в чем не бывало? Где-то неявно указывается его открытие через Node?

В общем, интересует, как можно создать подобного рода пакет, чтобы сразу при его установке добавлялась ссылка на .js файл в путь к node'у, чтобы мой пакет можно было запустить прямо из терминала.

Благодарю.

P.S. Если где-то путаю термины, то прошу меня поправить, ибо только начинаю разбираться во всей этой каше.

---

По просьбе "сформулировать вопрос более точно".
Как создать npm-пакет, который будет иметь возможность запускаться прямо из терминала по своему имени? Подробности описаны выше.

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос более точно - это поможет и отвечающим, и тем кто будет искать ответы

Comment: @MikhailVaysman уточнил как смог. Что еще добавить, не совсем понимаю. Спрашивайте, будут ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За это отвечает секция `bin` в `package.json`:

```
"bin": {
  "mytool": "bin/tool.js"
}
```

`tool.js`, в свою очередь, должен содержать так называемый шебанг - 
  `#!/usr/bin/env node`, например.

При установке такого пакета, в `node_modules/.bin` появится исполняемый бинарник mytool. Точнее симлинк `mytool -> ../yourpackage/bin/tool.js`.

Запускать локально установленные утилиты можно как `$(npm bin)/mytool`

При установке пакета с -g он попадёт в глобальный node_modules/.bin, который присутствует в $PATH. Тогда его можно вызывать просто, как `mytool`.

Comment: То есть если бы я установил express-generator без опции -g, то я бы не мог его в дальнейшем запускать из терминала? Прямо по имени.

Comment: И еще. Насчет шебангов - это ведь справедливо только для *nix'ов, так?

Comment: Да, но мог бы через `$(node bin)/express-generator`. Это полезно, когда в разных проектах нужно иметь разные версии утилит

Comment: В windows, shebang игнорируется, чтобы это работало, нужна ассоциация js файлов c бинарником node.js.. Но в этом я не вполне уверен. =)

Comment: Что ж, спасибо и на том. Сейчас попробовал поиграться с этим всем, в итоге, вроде бы, все получилось. Благодарю за объяснения.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример такого пакета

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myscript",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Do nothing",
  "license": "MIT",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "myscript": "index.js"
  }
}
```

**preferGlobal** указывает, что это пакет преимущественно запускается в командной строке и его надо установить глобально - ключ `-g`, если устанавливать без этого ключа, то будет выдано предупреждение.

**bin** указывает какой будет создан **symlink**. Ключ - это имя **symlink** (вашей команды, express, например), а значение - это файл, на который этот **symlink** указывает. В случае с **express-generator** там будет

```
"bin":{"express":"./bin/express-cli.js"}
```

**index.js**

Первая строчка указывает как именно запускать этот файл.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('Script is running');
```

**index.js** нужно сделать исполняемым

```
chmod +x index.js
```

Для проверки этого пакета в процессе разработки необходимо выполнить вот эту команду.

```
npm link
```

И вы получите возможность запускать `myscript` в терминале.

После публикации пакета в **npmjs** он будет работать как все остальные пакеты.

Comment: Так, давайте по-порядку. `preferGlobal` играет какую-нибудь роль? Дальше. Раздел "bin". `myscript` здесь означает то, что я буду писать в терминале, а `index.js` - то, что будет обрабатывать вызов? И еще. Вот эти выдачи прав на запуск, линкование - почему это приходится делать вручную? Тот же express-generator сделал все самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо. Про preferGlobal действительно полезно.

Comment: Всё, что делает preferGlobal - warning, если пакет установлен без -g.

Comment: А зачем делать исполняемым?

Comment: @Qwertiy что бы при `npm link` работал